# React - How to get client coordinates on canvas properly? (drawing a straight line with mouse)

Tags: reactjs, canvas, use-effect, use-state

I got to make "drawing a line" works, but this line wouldn't start from where my mouse starts, rather it'd start from very beginning {x: 0, y:0}. How to draw a line starting from where my mouse clicks?

I already used e.nativeEvent.offsetX and e.nativeEvent.offsetY for getting client X and Y, and this is used for just drawing feature, but I'm stuck how I can utilize it for drawing line, or changing my draw a line code for making it work. Thank you in advanced!

```
const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const ctxRef = useRef(null);
  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false);
  const [lineWidth, setLineWidth] = useState(5);
  const [lineColor, setLineColor] = useState("black");
  
  let startPosition = {x: 0, y: 0};
  let lineCoordinates = {x: 0, y: 0}; 

  const getClientOffset = (e) => {
    const {pageX, pageY} = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
    const x = pageX - canvasRef.offsetLeft;
    const y = pageY - canvasRef.offsetTop;

    return {
       x,
       y
    } 
  } 

  const drawLine = () => {
   ctxRef.current.beginPath();
   ctxRef.current.moveTo(startPosition.x, startPosition.y);
   ctxRef.current.lineTo(lineCoordinates.x, lineCoordinates.y);
   ctxRef.current.stroke();
}

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = lineColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctxRef.current = ctx;
  }, [lineColor, lineWidth]);

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    setIsDrawing(true);

    // const posX = e.nativeEvent.offsetX;
    // const posY = e.nativeEvent.offsetY;

    // ctxRef.current.beginPath();
    // ctxRef.current.moveTo(
    //   posX,
    //   posY
    // );
    startPosition = getClientOffset(e);
  }

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!isDrawing) {
      return;
    } 
    ctxRef.current.lineTo(
      e.nativeEvent.offsetX,
      e.nativeEvent.offsetY
    );
    ctxRef.current.stroke();

    lineCoordinates = getClientOffset(e);
    drawLine();
  }

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    ctxRef.current.closePath();
    setIsDrawing(false);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `let startPosition` and `let lineCoordinates` – on each render update React will reinitialize these variables with `{x: 0, y:0}`. In order to remember any value you must use `useState()`.

I tried it out in a demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-breeze-xj26c?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you! Somehow, it wouldn't "draw" a line without adding this line of code, so I added this:  

ctxRef.current.lineTo(
      e.nativeEvent.offsetX,
      e.nativeEvent.offsetY,
    );
ctxRef.current.stroke();

and by adding the code for clearing the canvas, it worked, but now it wouldn't "save" the drawing, it'd delete the previous line every time before drawing a new line, and the start coordinates aren't where my mouse clicks, rather it starts from absolute 0, 0... would you help with these?

Comment: @Sops I edited the answer. Let me know if it works or please accept the answer if it solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! Actually, the demo doesn't work on my end, but I figured to store those two things in states, and it worked. 
And, I still have some issues with this - when drawing a new line, it'll draw a new line from the starting point, but I see "connecting line" between those two points real quick before I draw a new line. Not sure what to do with it! And... I'd like to draw multiple lines, not only one line, but right now, I can draw only one line as it'll delete the previous line every time when drawing a new line :'(

Comment: @Sops I fixed the demo, forgot to save some changes. For multiple lines you need to store an arrays of lines. That's the tricky part of canvas, you have to memorize everything to be able to redraw it.